# monodevelop gtk# button on top of webview

Tags: button, webkit, monodevelop, gtk#

question about monodevelop and Gtk#. I want to put the button on top of WebKit.WebView, but cannot figure out the way to do so. WebView renders on top of button... I try to achieve it using Gtk.Fixed as following:

```
    Gtk.ScrolledWindow htmlScroll= new Gtk.ScrolledWindow();
    WebKit.WebView htmlView = new WebView ();
    Gtk.Fixed myFixed = new Gtk.Fixed();

    Gtk.Button btn= new Gtk.Button();
    btn.Visible = true;
    btn.Label = "scrl test button";

    htmlScroll.Add(htmlView);

    myFixed.Put (htmlScroll, 20, 0);
    myFixed.Put(btn, 0, 0);
```

The button is parent for webview. In case I click on the webview area which overlaps with button, the button gets clicked (part of the button is visible). But webview is rendered on top of button. Any hint is highly appreciated.

BR, Madis

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Gtk.Fixed? If you just want to align the button above the WebView, Gtk.VBox is what you need. With Gtk.Fixed you need not only to initialize the positions manually, you also need to readjust them after the widgets have been realized and handle all the sizing manually.

Comment: My explanation of the goal is a bit misleading, probably. I mean that I want the button to overlap with with WebView. You are right, vbox allows to align the button "on top of webiew", but what I really need it button overlappin the webview. I found out that gtk.fixed is one way of doing it... And here comes the problem. Button is there, overlapping with with webview, functions correctly, but is drawn behind the webview...

Comment: how do you get webview? i couldn't find webview in monodevelop...